# How to get rid of unnecessary values on the y-axis with subplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, axis, subplot

I have those two databases (df2020 and data2020) :

[image: df1]

[image: df2]

And I made two subplot out of it with this code :

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(15,5))

    
X1 = df2020['month']
Y1 = df2020['notes']
ticks = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

ax = f.add_subplot(121)
ax.bar(X1, Y1, facecolor = '#9999ff', edgecolor = 'white')
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
ax.set_ylabel('Ratings')
ax.set_title('Evolution des notes durant 2020');

    
for x,y in zip(X1,Y1):
    plt.text(x, y, y, ha='center', va= 'bottom')

X2 = data2020['month']
Y2 = data2020['comms']

ax2 = f.add_subplot(122)
ax2.bar(X2, Y2, facecolor = '#9999ff', edgecolor = 'white')
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
ax2.set_ylabel('Ratings')
ax2.set_title('Evolution du nombre de commentaires durant 2020');

    
for x,y in zip(X2,Y2):
    plt.text(x, y, y, ha='center', va= 'bottom')
```

And here's the output :

[image: graphe]

But as you can see, there is a minor issue with this graphic and I kind of understand why. There is some kind of pregeneric value on the x-axis (0.0 to 1.0) and on the y-axis (0.0 to 1.0) and one 0 on the right, and for both graphic. I don't know how to get rid of them, I tried to specify `set_ylim` or `set_ytickslabel` but it change only the value I would like to keep (the 0.0 to 5.0 value on the y-axis and the date on the x-axis).

What should I do to fix this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are first creating four (empty) subplots using `f, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 5))`, and then creating new subplots on top of them using `f.add_subplot`.

You can immediately use the `axs` variable created by `plt.subplots` to plot your data, you do not explicitly need to create subplots afterwards. Do note that you are currently creating a 2×2 grid of subplots, while you want to create a 1×2 grid (row).

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5))

X1 = df2020['month']
Y1 = df2020['notes']
ticks = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

axs[0].bar(X1, Y1, facecolor = '#9999ff', edgecolor = 'white')
plt.setp(axs[0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
axs[0].set_ylabel('Ratings')
axs[0].set_title('Evolution des notes durant 2020')

for x,y in zip(X1,Y1):
    axs[0].text(x, y, y, ha='center', va= 'bottom')

X2 = data2020['month']
Y2 = data2020['comms']

axs[1].bar(X2, Y2, facecolor = '#9999ff', edgecolor = 'white')
plt.setp(axs[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
axs[1].set_ylabel('Ratings')
axs[1].set_title('Evolution du nombre de commentaires durant 2020')

for x,y in zip(X2,Y2):
    axs[1].text(x, y, y, ha='center', va= 'bottom')
```

Comment: Awesome, that's work ! Just one thing, I think you forgot (nevermind you just edited your post). Thank you for your help. I will not forget to use the `axs` right after the creation by `plt.subplot`. Thank you a lot :)